# Jquery testing using jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I am very beginner in jasmine. I dont Know how to test this following jquery code using jasmine.

```
 if ($('.data-block').length > 0) {
   $('.span4:even', '.data-block').addClass('even');
   $('.span4:odd', '.data-block').addClass('odd');
 }
```

Can you tell me how i write the testing code using jasmine for about this jquery program. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Jasmine-JQuery plugin and test against an injected DOM:

https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery

The plugin provides custom matchers such as:

```
expect($('.span4:even')).toHaveAttr('class', 'even')
```

Ps
Here you have a [short introduction](http://testdrivenwebsites.com/2010/07/29/html-fixtures-in-jasmine-using-jasmine-jquery/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here how may i merge my jquery code in to jasmine code?

Comment: If I correctly understand your question, you have to abstract the portion of markup you intend to test info a fixture file, and then check your logic against this markup. The process is well explained in the github page, you have to use loadFixtures() method to load the markup, let your code run against this markup, and then verify that the output is correct (by using jasmine matchers).

Comment: describe("Hello world", function() {
      it("says hello", function() {
      expect($('.span4:even')).toHaveAttr('class', 'even')
      });
    });

its enough?